# How to call custom function on hover with delay in jquery

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-hover

I suppose it's something simple but just can't get my syntax to work.

I created a function that displays popup box with user info, called 'displayUserinfo' (there's a lot of code to it so I guess no point to paste it in). When user clicks on `$('.avatar')` class, function is launched:

`$('.avatar').on('click', displayUserinfo);`

And this part works perfctly. Now I want to add code that will launch the same function when user hovers over the `$('.avatar')` for 2 seconds, but that's where function is not being launched (console.logs are there to test if it's working and they both do):

```
var timer;
var delay = 2000;

$('.avatar').hover(function() {
    console.log('test1');
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('test2');
        $('.avatar').displayUserinfo;
    }, delay);
}, function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    console.log('test3');
});
```

I tried `$(this).displayUserinfo` but didn't work either.

Can anyone give me a hand on that please?

Comment: Apropos of not very much, I can't *stand* all of these things that pop up when I just move my mouse (or stop moving it for two seconds). Please, please just wait for me to click. (I'm looking at you, Google, and your stupid 18 different hover popups in Gmail. And you, Microsoft, and the truly awful taskbar hover behavior in Windows 7 and 8.)

Comment: Haha, allright, I will consider that comment, might be a valid one since laptops are turning touchscreens. Nonetheless I would like to learn how to get this stuff to work

Comment: Yes, good point about touchscreens!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
$('.avatar').displayUserinfo;
```

...looks for any elements with the `avatar` class and wraps them in a jQuery object, then accesses a `displayUserinfo` property on that jQuery object (which is probably `undefined`) — and then does nothing with it. It doesn't, for instance, call a function (other than `$()`).

I think you probably wanted:

```
var hovered = this;
```

just inside the `hover` callback, and then this inside the `setTimeout` callback:

```
displayUserinfo.call(hovered);
```

That calls the `displayUserinfo` function, using the element that was hovered as `this` during the call (the way `on` does).

In situ:

```
var timer;
var delay = 1000;

$('.avatar').hover(function() {
    var hovered = this;
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('test2');
        displayUserinfo.call(hovered);
    }, delay);
}, function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

---

Side note: The delay in your code is only one second, not two.

Comment: Fantastic, worked exactly as I wanted (I also fixed the sidenote). Just a quick question, if I'd like to cancel the function `displayUserinfo` (make popup disappear) after moving mouse away from the Popup (NOT avatar), would that be the same hover function, or different one since now I's not addressing $('.avatar'), but $('.popup')?

Comment: @Pejs: Right, a different one.